RuntimeError: Cannot unlink unmanageable packages: torchvision, torchaudio error trying to update conda environment
Get the following in terminal when running conda install.
The only way I can install packages is to delete the conda environment and install from everything from scratch.
conda install django-environ
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
 - nvidia
 - pytorch
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | WARNING conda.conda_libmamba_solver.solver:_export_solved_records(832): Tried to unlink torchaud?
WARNING conda.conda_libmamba_solver.solver:_export_solved_records(832): Tried to unlink torchvision-0.18.1-py3.11.egg-i?
done

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 18, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in main_subshell
        exit_code = do_call(args, parser)
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 200, in do_call
        result = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\notices\core.py", line 132, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 152, in execute
        return install(args, parser, "install")
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 377, in install
        unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 153, in solve_for_transaction
        unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(
      File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 239, in solve_for_diff
        raise RuntimeError(
    RuntimeError: Cannot unlink unmanageable packages:
      - pypi/pypi::torchvision-0.18.1-pypi_0
      - pypi/pypi::torchaudio-2.3.1-pypi_0

Contents of environment.yaml
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - pytorch
  - nvidia
  - nodefaults

dependencies:
 - python=3.11.*
 - pip
 - pytest
 - pytorch::pytorch
 - pytorch::torchvision
 - pytorch::torchaudio
 - pytorch-cuda=12.1
 - ultralytics
 - numpy
 - opencv
 - matplotlib
 - pandas 
 - joblib
 - kornia>=0.6.11
 - google-cloud-vision
 - django-environ


OS: Windows 11
Python: 3.11.9
pip: 24.0
conda: 24.5.0


What is the curreent content of the environment? Post the output of conda list and what is the conda install command that you are trying to use?

The conda install command is conda install django-environ in this case, but it didn't work with any package.
I deleted the conda environment so I don't have conda list available. I switched over to poetry and it works just fine. I don't think the problem was a conflict with other packages. The error seems specifically related to the pytorch packages.

The error is most likely necause you had installed pytorch using pip. Your install command caused conda to try to update pytorch, which it refused to do, because it detected that the package was installed using pip.

Everything was installed using conda env create -f environment.yml -p ./venv

But you're right that is weird that it says pypi/pypi::torchvision and not pytorch::. I don't believe I ever installed anything in this project using pip, since pytorch requires python <3.12 right now and I'm using the package manager to specify python version.
